# chunk list of objects by property sum

Tags: python

I want to chunk a list of objects in order that the sum of a property is less than a value, let say `10`.

```
lst = [{"value": 1}, {"value": 8}, {"value": 2}, {"value": 6}, {"value": 1}, {"value": 9}, {"value": 10}]

result = [[{"value": 1}, {"value": 8}], [{"value": 2}, {"value": 6}, {"value": 1}], [{"value": 9}], [{"value": 10}]]
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
def chunks_by_prop_sum(lst, prop, max_per_chunk):
    chunks = []
    chunk_prop_sum = 0
    chunk = []
    for i in range(0, len(lst)):
        if chunk_prop_sum <= max_per_chunk- lst[i][prop]
            chunk.append(lst[i])
            chunk_prop_sum += lst[i][prop]
        else:
            chunks.append(chunk.copy())
            chunk = []
            chunk_prop_sum = 0

    return chunks
```

I would like to improve that function by making a generator if possible and also to handle when an object value is greater than the max per chunk threshold.

The order of objects in chunks matter.

Comment: Do you want to _use_ a generator or to _make_ a generator?

Comment: I corrected my question, making a generator :)

Comment: Does my answer to the original question answer your updated question?

Comment: @0x263A Yes, actually making or using a generator does not matter for me in fact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of converting your function to a generator:

```
original = [{"value": 1}, {"value": 8}, {"value": 2}, {
    "value": 6}, {"value": 1}, {"value": 9}, {"value": 10}]


def my_chunks(lst, val, n):
    chunk, chunk_sum = [], 0
    while chunk_sum < n and lst:
        if lst[0][val] >= n:
            if chunk:
                yield chunk
            yield [lst.pop(0)]
            chunk, chunk_sum = [], 0
        # We could also use the walrus operator here
        # elif (tot:= chunk_sum + lst[0][val]) < n:
        #   chunk_sum = tot
        elif chunk_sum + lst[0][val] < n:
            chunk_sum += lst[0][val]
            chunk.append(lst.pop(0))
        else:
            yield chunk
            chunk, chunk_sum = [], 0
    if chunk:
        yield chunk


result = [[{"value": 1}, {"value": 8}], [{"value": 2}, {
    "value": 6}, {"value": 1}], [{"value": 9}], [{"value": 10}]]
print([*my_chunks(original, 'value', 10)] == result)
```

Outputs:

```
True
```

The idea here is to build a chunk in the while loop and yield then "reset" it when the sum of the objects in the chunk is greater than n. When the loop encounters an object with a value greater than n it yields the prior chunk if it exists then the object in a chunk of its own.

Comment: I dont understand why the `while chunk_sum < n and lst:` Should it be just `while lst:` to be sure the whole list is yielded? Otherwise that answer is really good!

Answer (score 2):

This is building a generator, but also without using any if statements and not a lot of code.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def chunks_by_prop_sum(data:list[dict], prop:str, max_per_chunk:int) -> list[list[dict]]:
    res = defaultdict(list)
    total, inc = 0, 0
    for entry in data:
        total += entry[prop]
        res[(total // max_per_chunk) + inc].append(entry)
        inc += int(entry[prop] >=  max_per_chunk)
    return list(res.values())

print(chunks_by_prop_sum(lst, 'value', 10))
```

Comment: Is it python3? syntax in the function parameters seems weird to me... I got a typeError object is not callable

Comment: 3.9 You can ditch those annotations if you don't need them or exchange with List and Dict from the typing module. I just always type annotated code...

Answer (score 1):

There is another option. It is quite neat:

```
def chunks_by_prop_sum(lst, prop, max_per_chunk):
    out = []
    cum = 0
    for item in lst:
        if out and cum + item[prop] > max_per_chunk:
            yield out
            out = []
            cum = 0
        out.append(item)
        cum += item[prop]
    yield out
    
rv = list(chunks_by_prop_sum(lst, "value", 10))
print(rv == result)
```

Output:

```
True
```